# Delete and recreate a sheet will change nothing on the computations

Tags: excel

Assume I have an Excel file with two sheets : `Data` and `Computation`. As the names say, `Data` contains only data (e.g. NHL player statistics) and `Computation` makes computations in using the data from `Data`.

Suppose that I delete intentionally the `Data` sheet, then the computations are breaking in `Computation` sheet (perfectly normal). If I recreate the same sheet with the same name, the computations in `Computation` sheet is till broken.

From now on, I would like if I make a simple sum in `Data` sheet from `Computation` sheet that it will reference the file and not the cells. In other words, if I delete the sheet and recreate it with the same name, then it will change nothing.

Is it possible to do that? Could anyone be able to give me a simple example.

Please let me know if the question is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, but not recommended. You can use `INDIRECT` for this.

For example, the following formula would return whatever is in cell A1 on whatever sheet is called "Data".

```
= INDIRECT("Data!A1")
```

Comment: `=+INDIRECT("SUM(Sheet1!A1:A4)")` give me `#REF`. How could I fix it?

Comment: @J.Doe `INDIRECT` can only take a *cell range within quotes* as an argument, not a *formula*. To fix, do this: `=SUM(INDIRECT("Sheet1!A1:A4"))`